# Null Pointer Exception When Search a Char Sequence in a string

Tags: android

I am parsing an xml using DOM Parser. I get a doc and then from that doc i get a url. when i search through that url for a particular char sequence i receive a null pointer exception.
This is what i am doing:

```
  Boolean var = false;
  String url = theElement.getChildNodes().item(5).getNodeValue();
    if (url.contains("-b-"))  // this throws exception
    {
      var = true;
    }
```

Please any suggestions...

Comment: check your string url it might be null

Comment: No it is not infact. I have checked it.

Comment: @Usama: That sounds very unlikely. If you believe it really isn't null, then you should be able to change the long line with lots of dereferences for a string literal and see the same result...

Comment: @Jon you are right but how do i believe when console shows me the url printed absolutely fine. anyway, now check for individual elements. hope i find the root cause.

Comment: @Usama: I suspect there's something wrong with the way you're interpreting the debug information - e.g. you're seeing a previous iteration of the loop, or something like that. Print it out directly before your `if` statement, and add another message *just before* the line which assigns a value to `url`, and another one after the `if` block, so you can see *exactly* where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These long chains of "dereference" operations often cause problems if one or more of them results in a null pointer.

Before setting `url`, print out the values for:

```
theElement
theElement.getChildNodes()
theElement.getChildNodes().item(5)
theElement.getChildNodes().item(5).getNodeValue();
```

Almost certainly the last one will be a null reference.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) for `String.contains` shows no specific exception is thrown, hence the likelihood is high that it's a null reference (especially, as I've just noticed, you explicitly state that it's a null pointer exception).

Comment: Xup, This is what confusing me that String.contains throws no exception but still it is thrown. Anyway, I check for all individual values.

Comment: @Usama, it contains no _specific_ exception. But if you try to do `nullreference.anything()`, you'll get a null pointer exception  regardless of what the docs say. The docs will only list exceptions thrown specifically, not those caused by trying to dereference a null (which is more of a language thing than a library thing).